# Create a reponsive event marker

Tags: css, web, responsive-design

i want to make my marker responsive i have a link `<a>` attribute with defined class fc-event and i want to place it inside or behind the `<td>` which is inside my `thead`.

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
          <td><span class="fc-day-number">10</span></td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <a class=" fc-event "><div class="fc-content"><span>12a</span></div></a>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Below is the approached i used only problem is that it is not responsive

```
.fc-event {
     display: block; /*This is the approach*/
     border-radius: 100%;
     width: 40px;
     height: 40px;
     background-color: rgba(3,169,244,0.71);
     top: 1;
     margin-left: 5%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give us more details?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I want to place the blue circle maker which is an "<a>" and is within my tbody maker on top of the day e.g the 10th and the day is placed in my thead and each and every time i reduce the calendar the blue circle marker doesnt move with the day.